# passing pointer to dll class function

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

I need to build an executable which loads the dll @ runtime and call the c++ function inside the dll with multiple parameters. I have seen plenty of examples which tells me about how to pass a parameter, but in my case it not exactly the same way. I need to pass 3 parameters.

1. Struct with 3 `std::string` elements
2. Struct pointer with `std::map` and `std::string`, and the `map` has `std::string` as key and structure as value
3. Struct with `std::unordered_map` which also has `std::string` as key and `std::string` as value, some `bool`, integer elements.

The dll class is derived from 2 base classes. ex: `BaseClassA` --> `BaseClassB` --> `DerivedClassA`

I have created the factory function and made all the `__dllspec(dllexport)` correctly but when I try to create `DerivedClassA` instance I got exceptions

```
Unhandled exception at 0x759FA6F2 in rte.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x016FF1C4
```

My Code Snippet (dllhelp.h):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cinttypes>

typedef uint32_t   ID;

typedef ID EVENT_UID;

typedef struct {
    EVENT_UID m_unEventID;
    uint8_t  *m_ptrMemAddr;
    size_t    m_dataSize;
}stEvent_t;

typedef struct  {
    uint32_t    m_unOffset;
    uint32_t    m_unArraySize;
    std::string m_acTagName;
    std::string m_acTagValue;
    std::string m_acDataType;
} stTagElem_t;

typedef std::unordered_map<uint8_t, stTagElem_t> tagsList_t;

typedef struct  {
    EVENT_UID    m_unBindedEvent;
    uint16_t     m_unMemSize;
    tagsList_t   m_stTagsList;
    std::string  m_acMapTypeName;
} stElem_t;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, stElem_t> ElemList_t;

typedef struct  {
    std::string   m_acAppBlocName;
    std::string   m_acInstanceName;
    std::string   m_acDataMapInstanceName;
    std::string   m_acTypeName;
} stBlock_t;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string > instanceTypeList_t;

typedef struct {
    bool               m_bIsItOutput;
    uint8_t            m_unIdxToEvtClient;
    EVENT_UID          m_acBindedEvent;
    instanceTypeList_t m_acParamsList;
} stParams_t;

#ifdef EXPORTING_EXTN
#define RTE_EXTN __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RTE_EXTN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class RTE_EXTN BaseA {
public:
  BaseA(){}
  virtual ~BaseA(){}
  void rxdEvent(stEvent_t pa_stEvent){ onRxdEvent(pa_stEvent);}
protected:
  virtual void onRxdEvent(stEvent_t pa_stEvent); 
};

class RTE_EXTN BaseB : public BaseA {
public:
  BaseB(stParams_t pa_stParams){;}
  virtual ~BaseB(){}
  void sendOutput(size_t dataSize);
  virtual int initialise() {return -1;}
  virtual void onRxdEvent(stEvent_t pa_stEvent) {};
  stBlock_t m_stBlock;
  stElem_t  *m_stElem;
protected:
  stEvent_t m_stEvent;
  stParams_t m_stParams;
};

class RTE_EXTN DerivedClassA : public BaseB {
public:
  DerivedClassA(stBlock_t pa_stBlock, stElem_t *pa_stElem, stParams_t pa_stParams) : BaseB(pa_stParams){
    m_stElem = pa_stElem;
    m_stBlock = pa_stBlock;
  }
  int initialise(){return 0;}
  void onRxdEvent(stEvent_t pa_stEvent);
};

extern "C" {
  RTE_EXTN BaseB* CreateDerivedObj(stBlock_t pa_stBlock, stElem_t *pa_stElem, stParams_t pa_stParams);
};

typedef BaseB* (*CreateDrvObjType_t) (stBlock_t pa_stBlock, stElem_t *pa_stElem, stParams_t pa_stParams);
```

My dllmain.cpp:

```
#include "dllhelp.h"
BaseA* CreateDerivedObject(stBlock_t pa_stBlock, stElem_t *pa_stElem, stParams_t pa_stParams)
{       
    return new DerivedClassA(pa_stBlock, pa_stElem, pa_stParams);
}
```

My main executable:

```
stBlock_t   m_siInfo;
stElem_t    *pa_stElem;
stParams_t  m_siParams;
//the above structures are initialized and updated with valid data..

HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL_derived;
typedef BaseB* (*CreateDrvObjType_t) (stBlock_t pa_stBlock, stElem_t *pa_stElem, stParams_t pa_stParams);
hGetProcIDDLL_derived = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dllhelp.dll")); 
CreateDrvObjType_t oExtension = reinterpret_cast<CreateDrvObjType_t>(GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL_derived, "CreateDerivedObj"));
BaseB* paDrvObj = oExtension(m_siInfo,pa_stElem,m_siParams);
```

When trying debug mode, I am able to see all the structures were filled with valid elements. But while debugging on the dllmain.cpp, I wasn't able to see any valid data on the structures. Some points to null address, and some to invalid data and many say "Error reading character string".

## Note: I don't use dllhelp.h file in my main executable. Rather I have declared all the structures in main file itself.

Comment: Are you compiling the DLL and main executable with the same compiler options?

Comment: Yes it is.. both use the same compiler options. Should I need to create .def file?